improved impossible differential crpytanalysis of 6-round rijndael
I'm studying the paper: "Improved Impossible Differential Cryptanalysis of Rijndael and Crypton".
I've got two questions:

Please explain the calculation performed for step 5?


Step 4 requires about $2^{123.5} (= 2 \times 2^{64} \times 2^{58.5})$ one round operations. Step 5 requires about $2^{119}$ one round operations since:
$2^{64} \times 2 \times 2^{32}\{1 + (1 - 2^{-22}) + (1 - 2^{-22})^2 + \ldots + (1 - 2^{-22})^{2^{28.5}}\} \approx 2^{119}$


How many pairs are needed to delete $k_0$'s corresponding to $k_6$




Include a description of the step or a link to the paper please

@kodlu It was added to the question. I'll be danged if I convert that to MathJax though :)

This attack article has little application with those fixed plaintexts and 6 rounds and $2^{91.5}$ chosen plaintexts.
